# Picking number randomly from a list of n numbers in Hive

Tags: hive

Is there a function in **HIVE** that can help me to select a number randomly from a list.
For example : I want to select a random number from below list

```
1000
2000
4000
6000
8000
10000
```

P.S. these values are not present in a table, we have 6 different hardcoded variables, we need to select one of them.

Comment: When is this randomly selected number needed?

Comment: Why isn't putting them in a table an option?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by constructing an Array of the possible values, and using `RAND()` to pick one:

```
SELECT Array(1000, 2000, 6000, 8000, 10000)[Cast((FLOOR(RAND()*5.0)+1) as INT)];
```

Comment: Hi mattinbits, thanks a lot for replying. I tried this but as Array does not support non constant datatypes, it is throwing an error. It is expecting a constant value in [] square bracket, but then how will i pass the random number :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a, b, c,
  CASE WHEN nonsense <=1.0 THEN  1000
       WHEN nonsense <=2.0 THEN  2000
       ...
       WHEN nonsense <=5.0 THEN  8000
       ELSE                     10000
  END AS more_nonsense
FROM
 (SELECT a, b, c, RAND()*6.0 AS nonsense
  FROM ...
  WHERE ...
 ) x
```

*"When everything else has failed, consider reading the documentation":*

[DOUBLE rand()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-MathematicalFunctions)

> Returns a random number (that changes from row to row) that is
>   distributed uniformly from 0 to 1.

[CASE WHEN ELSE END](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions)